# Nuances in the difference between a class declaration and definition

Tags: c++

In C++ you can re-declare many times but define only once. When you write a class it's both a definition and declaration so once you include that in multiple .cc files aren't you re-defining as well? What am I missing?

Comment: A declaration says it exists.  A definition says what exists.

Comment: The One Definition Rule allows multiple definitions of classes (in different Translation Units / .cc files), if those definitions are "equivalent", i.e. satisfy a certain list of requirements.